# Недоступны идентификаторы элементов шаблона разметки в мультимодульном андроид-приложении c ButterKnife

Tags: android, android-fragment, butterknife

Возникла проблема недоступности идентификаторов элементов шаблона разметки в мультимодульном андроид-приложении, использующем Fragment, Moxy, ButterKnife и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## module_00_lib\src\main\res\layout\module_goods_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/goodsToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

## module_00_lib\src\main\res\layout\module_00_fragment_recycler_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.module_00_lib.ui.fragment
        .recycler.RecyclerGoodsListFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/module_goods_toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvGoodsList"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

15.09.17 По подсказке добавляю код файлов скриптов сборки:

## build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## module_00_lib\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 
            "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [ moxyReflectorPackage : 
                    'com.example.module_00_lib' ]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def support = '26.+'
def retrofit = '2.3.0'
def glide = '3.7.0'
def moxy = '1.5.3'
def butterKnife = '8.6.0'

dependencies {
    compile project (':_service_lib')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:
        espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', 
                   module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$support"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$support"

    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"

    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide"

    compile "com.arello-mobile:moxy:$moxy"
    compile "com.arello-mobile:moxy-app-compat:$moxy"
    annotationProcessor "com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:$moxy"

    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnife"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnife"

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1-rc1'
}
```

При этом если отказаться от ButterKnife, то всё работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в MainActivity всё работает и с ButterKnife.

Что и где нужно изменить, чтобы ButterKnife во фрагменте заработал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID в библиотеках да, не final, засим их и не применить. Стандартным способом.

Но в butterKnife для сих целей есть ещё один R class c названием R2. Т.е. при использовании разметки из библиотек делайте так:

```
BindView(R2.id.ID)
```

Также, согласно [README](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#library-projects), в ваших библиотеках надо добавить плагин в скрипт сборки модуля либы:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
 apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

Comment: Ссылка на R2 сразу подсвечивается красным. Возможно нужно ещё что-то где-то добавить?

Comment: @NonameNoferstname, дополнил ответ

Comment: После добавления в скрипт сборки модуля строки
"apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife" 
получил такую ошибку:
Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.jakewharton.butterknife' not found.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\bobkov-vv\AndroidStudioProjects-Gits\hybrid-template-android\module_00_lib\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Вот это из доки добавили в скипт уровня проекта?   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
  }
}

Comment: После добавления в блок dependencies раздела buildscript скрипта сборки проекта строки " classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1' " сообщения об ошибках при грэдлинге больше не появлялись, но "R2" всё равно подсвечивается красным.

Comment: Ну... А ребилд проекта делали? А импорт для R2 сделали?

Comment: Заработало!!!!!! Спасибо-о-о-о-о-о!!!!

Comment: @Noname Noferstname если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)